# why jsoup remove inlined stylesheet?

Tags: java, html, jsoup, sanitize

i use jsoup for protect my app from XSS attack. i get all all input parameter and do Jsoup.clean on thats. but i have a problem with that.

it remove all inlined stylesheet! why? i have a part in my app that user can write a text and publish it as a announcement. he/she writes him/her text via TinyMCE and it add some html and stylesheet to user text. in the following you can see a example text created by tinymce:

User input:  `Center Aligned Text`
TinyMCE result : `<p style="text-align: center;">Center Aligned Text</p>`
`Jsoup.clean(text, Whitelist.relaxed())` output : `<p>Center Aligned Text</p>`

As can see Jsoup remove style of

tag. how i can say to it that don't remove simple css?
thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default [Whitelist](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/safety/Whitelist.html) class removes style, but you can easily modify this behaviour and add support for `style` with `addAttributes("p", "style")`.

```
Whitelist.relaxed().addAttributes("p", "style");
```

**Explanation**

This set attribute `style` to element `p` as ignored under cleaning. Only `style` from `p` will be not removed!

---

### Verification code

Simply copy paste this code and invoke from `main`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "<p style=\"text-align: center;\">Center Aligned Text</p>";
    String clean = Jsoup.clean(text, Whitelist.relaxed()
            .addAttributes("p", "style"));
    System.out.println(clean);
}
```

### Result

```
<p style="text-align: center;">Center Aligned Text</p>
```

### Dependency

```
org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.3
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i use your solution but i there is not any change. its not work.

Comment: This code works for sure, I have tested it. Show me your code.

Comment: @RasoulTaheri My solution disables cleaning only for `style` from `p`!

Comment: You may use :all selector to allow certain attributes for all tags. Eg.: addAttributes(":all", "class", "style")

Comment: Thank you. Just what I need